# Looking way to create a relationship between entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have two entities one is employee and other one is project and i am looking to store the list of all bookmarked project ID's in employee entity and one employee can add bookmarks to multiple projects. One project can be bookmarked by multiple employees as well.

The employee entity structure is like this

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public List<Section> OwnedSections { get; set; } = new List<Section>();
    public List<string> BookmarkProjectsIDs { get; set; } // just specified the list of bookmark projectID's
}
```

and the below is the project entity structure

```
public class Project 
{
    [Key, GraphQLNonNullType]
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public ProjectSectionStatus SectionStatuses { get; set; } = new ProjectSectionStatus();
 }
```

Is this is right way to specify or is there any way we can specify just to store the ID's of projects and at the same time i do not want to duplicate the data as well. I am using Entity framework core with .Net core.

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the one to many relationship https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx there is more information on these pages then you will get an any single answer

Comment: I would just like to store the list of project Id's in employee table

Comment: It seems EF cannot do this, its a one to many relationship between Employee and Project, for EF you need to set a middle table between those two entity. But you can do it manually.

Comment: Databases don't have a *list* field, they have *primitive types* like `string` and `int`. Now, if you so choose you can smash a list of int into a string field, separated by commas, but this would (in any sane project) be the wrong approach, especially when you have linked tables, I would suggest reading the supplied documentation on one-to-many relationships.

Comment: @TheGeneral, Here one project can be bookmarked by multiple employees, and at the same time one employee can have multiple projects as well

Comment: Ahh ok, well that is called a many to many relationship, and very common. Have you looked at the documentation i supplied? are you having trouble understanding it?

Comment: @TheGeneral I don't want to create other join entity  where we will have project and employee inside that entity and with the above approach i feel like i am missing something about the relationship, could you please suggest any ideas on this..

Comment: @JackMartin is there any other way to achieve this not to creating middle table ..

Comment: AFAIK for EF the answer is None, but you can do it manually, write logical code in your controller/service and for that you will lose the power of EF(such as auto insert/update relations).